# Can I overcome the situation by some trick or indexing manipulation?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, relations

Let $G_i(N;x)=)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \binom{n}{i}n^i x^n$. From this I got,

$G_i(N;x) =1+x+x\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \sum_{j=0}^{i+1} \frac{1}{n-i+1} \color{blue}{\binom{n}{i}x^nn^j}  \binom{n+1}{j}-\binom{N}{i}N^ix^N \ \cdots (1)$

Here all $i,j,n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0 \}$

Now I want to replace the $\color{blue}{ \text{blue color part}}$ by $G_j(N;x)$ to get

$G_i(N;x) =1+x+x{\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}{\frac{1}{n-i+1}}} \sum_{j=0}^{i+1} G_j(N,x)  \binom{n+1}{j}-\binom{N}{i}N^ix^N \ \cdots (2)$.

But it is $\sum \binom{n}{i}x^nn^j$ not $\sum \binom{n}{j}x^nn^j$.

Can I overcome the situation by some trick or indexing manipulation ?

Help me

Comment: There does not appear to be any indication as to what "i" **means** here! 
"i" is simply an index on the entire quantity "G". Since you don't know what it means you can't touch it!

Comment: Here all $i,j,n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0 \}$

Comment: Did you check whether the identity is true for small values of $N$ and $i$?

Comment: @KBDave, which identity? Do you mean $\sum \binom{n}{i}x^in^j$ and $\sum \binom{n}{j}x^in^j$ ? or you mean $(2)$

Comment: (2); e.g., $N,i\in \{1,2,3\}$.